# Android RunningTaskInfo

Tags: android, activity-manager

could anyone explain why am I always gettin an runtimeException when calling `ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo` here's the code snippet:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> listInfo = am.getRunningTasks(2);
    ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo taskInfo = listInfo.get(0);//it throws exception in this line

    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Settings_Title);
    title.setText(taskInfo.topActivity.getClassName().toString());
```

Comment: Would you add your LogCat please!?

Comment: do i need any permission in manifest for this?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
final ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
final List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> listInfo = am.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
for (int i = 0; i < listInfo.size(); i++) 
{            
    if (listInfo.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString().indexOf("<yourproject>") > -1) {
        ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo taskInfo = listInfo.get(i);
    }
}
```

also try the following user permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_APP_TOKENS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```